WebSocket server echoes messages to wscat but not to JavaScript client
I'm working on a project where a C-based WebSocket server needs to communicate with a JavaScript client to change the color of an SVG element. The server should send messages to the JavaScript client when it receives commands from wscat. However, I'm facing an issue where the server echoes the messages back to wscat instead of the JavaScript client.
When I open index.html in a browser, I see the message "WebSocket is open now" in the console, indicating that the WebSocket connection is established. But when I send a command from wscat to the WebSocket server, the server only echoes the message back to wscat and not to the HTML page.
server.c
#include <libwebsockets.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static int callback_ws(struct lws *wsi, enum lws_callback_reasons reason,
                       void *user, void *in, size_t len) {
    switch (reason) {
        case LWS_CALLBACK_ESTABLISHED:
            printf("Connection established\n");
            break;
        case LWS_CALLBACK_RECEIVE:
            printf("%d\n", (int)len);
            char buffer[1024];
            if (len < sizeof(buffer) - 1) {
                memcpy(buffer, in, len);
                buffer[len] = '\0'; // Add null terminator at the end
                printf("Message received: %s\n", buffer);
                
                // Echo the message back to the client
                unsigned char message[LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING + len + LWS_SEND_BUFFER_POST_PADDING];
                memcpy(&message[LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING], buffer, len);
                lws_write(wsi, &message[LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING], len, LWS_WRITE_TEXT);
            }
            break;
        default:
            printf("Unhandled callback reason: %d\n", reason);
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}

static struct lws_protocols protocols[] = {
    { "ws", callback_ws, 0, 1024 },
    { NULL, NULL, 0, 0 } // Terminator
};

int main(void) {
    struct lws_context_creation_info info;
    memset(&info, 0, sizeof info);
    info.port = 8080;
    info.protocols = protocols;
    struct lws_context *context = lws_create_context(&info);

    if (context == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "lws init failed\n");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Starting server...\n");
    while (1) {
        lws_service(context, 1000); // 1000 ms = 1 second
    }

    lws_context_destroy(context);
    return 0;
}

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>WebSocket SVG Circle Color Change</title>
    <style>
        #mySVG {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <svg id="mySVG" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <circle id="myCircle" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="blue" />
    </svg>
    <p>Received message: <span id="messageDisplay"></span></p>

    <script>
        const socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080");

        socket.onopen = function(event) {
            console.log("WebSocket is open now.");
        };

        socket.onmessage = function(event) {
            console.log("WebSocket message received:", event.data);
            const messageDisplay = document.getElementById("messageDisplay");
            messageDisplay.textContent = event.data;

            const circle = document.getElementById("myCircle");

            // Assuming the message received is a color name or hex code
            circle.setAttribute("fill", event.data);
        };

        socket.onclose = function(event) {
            console.log("WebSocket is closed now.");
        };

        socket.onerror = function(error) {
            console.error("WebSocket error observed:", error);
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>

I've ensured that the WebSocket server runs on ws://localhost:8080 and the JavaScript client connects to the same address. The server successfully receives messages and prints them, but it only echoes them back to wscat.
How can I ensure that the messages are sent to the JavaScript client as well? What am I missing in the setup or implementation?

In your cpp code, you are only echoing the message back to the client that it came from, you need to also send that message to all other connected clients, if you want all the clients to receive the message. I don't use websockets, so perhaps this page can explain it better:   https://karlhadwen.medium.com/node-js-websocket-tutorial-real-time-chat-room-using-multiple-clients-44a8e26a953e

I recently encountered an issue where my WebSocket server, written in C using libwebsockets, was echoing messages back to wscat but not to my JavaScript client in an HTML page. Here's a summary of the problem and the solution I found.
The key was to broadcast messages to all connected clients. This involves tracking all connected clients and sending the message to each one. Here's the updated server code:
#include <libwebsockets.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Node for a linked list of WebSocket connections
typedef struct ws_client {
    struct lws *wsi;
    struct ws_client *next;
} ws_client_t;

static ws_client_t *clients = NULL;

// Add a client to the list
void add_client(struct lws *wsi) {
    ws_client_t *new_client = (ws_client_t *)malloc(sizeof(ws_client_t));
    new_client->wsi = wsi;
    new_client->next = clients;
    clients = new_client;
}

// Remove a client from the list
void remove_client(struct lws *wsi) {
    ws_client_t **current = &clients;
    while (*current) {
        if ((*current)->wsi == wsi) {
            ws_client_t *to_remove = *current;
            *current = (*current)->next;
            free(to_remove);
            return;
        }
        current = &((*current)->next);
    }
}

// Broadcast a message to all clients
void broadcast_message(const char *message, size_t len) {
    ws_client_t *current = clients;
    while (current) {
        lws_write(current->wsi, (unsigned char *)message, len, LWS_WRITE_TEXT);
        current = current->next;
    }
}

static int callback_ws(struct lws *wsi, enum lws_callback_reasons reason,
                       void *user, void *in, size_t len) {
    switch (reason) {
        case LWS_CALLBACK_ESTABLISHED:
            printf("Connection established\n");
            add_client(wsi);
            break;
        case LWS_CALLBACK_RECEIVE:
            printf("%d\n", (int)len);
            char buffer[1024];
            if (len < sizeof(buffer) - 1) {
                memcpy(buffer, in, len);
                buffer[len] = '\0'; // Add null terminator at the end
                printf("Message received: %s\n", buffer);

                // Broadcast the message to all clients
                broadcast_message(buffer, len);
            }
            break;
        case LWS_CALLBACK_CLOSED:
            printf("Connection closed\n");
            remove_client(wsi);
            break;
        default:
            printf("Unhandled callback reason: %d\n", reason);
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}

static struct lws_protocols protocols[] = {
    { "ws", callback_ws, 0, 1024 },
    { NULL, NULL, 0, 0 } // Terminator
};

int main(void) {
    struct lws_context_creation_info info;
    memset(&info, 0, sizeof info);
    info.port = 8080;
    info.protocols = protocols;
    struct lws_context *context = lws_create_context(&info);

    if (context == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "lws init failed\n");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Starting server...\n");
    while (1) {
        lws_service(context, 1000); // 1000 ms = 1 second
    }

    lws_context_destroy(context);
    return 0;
}

Here's the HTML file that changes the SVG circle color based on the received message, with case-insensitive handling and multiple color conditions:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>WebSocket SVG Circle Color Change</title>
    <style>
        #mySVG {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <svg id="mySVG" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <circle id="myCircle" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="blue" />
    </svg>
    <p>Received message: <span id="messageDisplay"></span></p>

    <script>
        const socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080");

        socket.onopen = function(event) {
            console.log("WebSocket is open now.");
        };

        socket.onmessage = function(event) {
            console.log("WebSocket message received:", event.data);
            const messageDisplay = document.getElementById("messageDisplay");
            messageDisplay.textContent = event.data;

            const circle = document.getElementById("myCircle");

            // Check if the received message is "Red"
            if (event.data.toLowerCase() === "red") {
                circle.setAttribute("fill", "red");
            }
            else if(event.data.toLowerCase()=== "black"){
                circle.setAttribute("fill", "black");
            }
        };

        socket.onclose = function(event) {
            console.log("WebSocket is closed now.");
        };

        socket.onerror = function(error) {
            console.error("WebSocket error observed:", error);
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>

By broadcasting the received messages to all connected clients, the WebSocket server now correctly sends messages to both wscat and the JavaScript client in the HTML page. This allows the JavaScript client to respond to commands and update the SVG element as intended.
